# I am trying to texture an object. But this keeps on happening

Tags: texturing

In the lower left hand box there is not the unwrapped figure.
[image]

Comment: If you do that on a simple cube, you will have the same result: all UV map faces overlap. You need to seam (mark seams) to open the mesh so that UV map can be developped

Comment: shouldnt is look like this

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+smart+uv+project&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX_Yi2oqTSAhWr7IMKHVstApUQ_AUICigD&biw=1600&bih=794#imgrc=cRKLKd34ABkm2M:

Comment: You can try to unwrap using 'smart uv project'... this is good but very dependent on the way you want to apply the textures. If not, mark seams... ctrl+E then 'mark seams' in edit mode

Comment: i did the smart uv project but it still ends up this way

Comment: Could you upload your file? You can do it here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2793" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2793/)

Comment: Well... unwrapping with 'smart UV project' works for me (on your mesh). In edit mode, select all the vertices, then 'U' to unwrap then choose 'smart uv project' and validate 'OK' for the widget that appears

Answer (score 0):

Few explanations.

If you unwrap directly using simple unwrap, blender won't guess how to open your mesh surface so it unwrap all faces on the texture bounds (that's what you obtain) :

[image]

If you use 'smart uv project', he will cut the mesh (depending on the options given in the widget following the command) to unwrap it and minimizing the lost space on the texture :

[image]

If you are not happy with the seams that Blender automatically does with 'smart UV project', mark the seams yourself:

[image]